# Filter checkboxes by CssClass and by Id

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an asp.net listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="MyListView" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3" >
          <LayoutTemplate>
             <table>
               <tr>
                 <td>
                   <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                   </table>
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <GroupTemplate>
            <tr>
              <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>
          </GroupTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
              <input class="Status-Checkbox"  id="StatusCheckBox" runat="server"  
                 type="checkbox" value=<%#Eval("StatusId")%> />
            </td>
          </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

In jquery, i have:

```
var MyStatId=MyStatId
```

The problem i that when the page is rendered the checkboxes  have dynamic id.
So i have to filter the checkbox by

> class=Status-Checkbox

and value, something like:

```
$('.Status-Checkbox').find(value=MyStatId)
```

Who has already done something like that?

Comment: Somebody please re-format this properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('.Status-Checkbox[val="whatever"]').each(function(){//dostuff});
```

When dealing with the dynamic ID thing. I prefer to add a custom attribute rather than relying on the ID. It does make finding items much much easier. If, for example you used your PK name of ("fieldName") as the attribute you could easily find it with:

```
$('.Status-Checkbox[fieldName="whatever"]').each(function(){//dostuff});
```

)

which IMO makes it clearer what you're looking for (should anyone else ever have to work on your code).

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of ASP.net include functionality to give you more control over IDs. You might look into that.

I've also done things where dynamically created IDs get written out to Javascript variables, something like `var jsVariableName='<%= Me.Textbox1.ClientID %>';`. That's a little more challenging with a list type control, but I bet it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use new feature of ASP.NET 4.0 - ClientIDMode. You can set an option to your server controls, to explicitly specify the way their clientId generated. In this case you can use Static mode:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <input class="Status-Checkbox" ClientIDMode="Static" 
id="StatusCheckBox_<%#Eval("StatusId")%>" runat="server" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

As a result your checkboxes will have ids like

```
StatusCheckBox_(YourStatusId1)
StatusCheckBox_(YourStatusId2)
```

etc. 
in generated html
so you can access them directly via

```
$('#StatusCheckBox_' + MyStatId)...
```

But you should check that this ids would be unique